# Tkinter canvas does not resize properly

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a game board that can resize automatically as the user resizes the window. I decided to use multiple canvases (planning to store them in a dictionary) instead of drawing rectangles on a single canvas because I thought it would be easier and nicer looking. I can't seem to resize the board properly, however. Here are the functions:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._root_window = tkinter.Tk()
    self._cols = 4
    self._rows = 4

    for row in range(self._rows):
        for col in range(self._cols):
            self._canvas = tkinter.Canvas(
                master = self._root_window, width = 50, height = 50, borderwidth = 0,
                highlightthickness = .5, background = '#C49B52',
                highlightbackground = 'black')

            self._canvas.grid(
                row = row, column = col, padx = 0, pady = 0,
                sticky = tkinter.N + tkinter.E + tkinter.S + tkinter.W)

            self._root_window.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
            self._root_window.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

def start(self) -> None:
    self._root_window.mainloop()
```

This is what happens when I try to resize the window:

http://vvcap.net/db/ZU7nvbjtGoDKpIyRXjVs.htp

I tried using `self._root_window.bind('<Configure>', self._resize)` and reprinting the board  through that, but this was the result (it also crashed when I tried stretching it):

http://vvcap.net/db/HqWzkb9_rVYfckPIuiRR.htp

How can I resize the board properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give each row and each column a *weight*, which describes how that row or column will grow or shrink when its container grows or shrinks. By default each row and column gets a weight of 0 (zero). In this case tkinter will pick the highest widget in the stacking order to grow or shrink, which is why the upper-left widget grows. The rest of the rows and columns expand only enough to accommodate that upper-left canvas.

Add the following to your code after your big for loop:

```
for row in range(self._rows):
    for col in range(self._cols):
        ...
for row in range(self._rows):
    self._root_window.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=1)
for col in range(self._cols):
    self._root_window.grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1)
```